How do I get client metadata with the client_credentials grant type?
My API supports both end-users and machine clients. I use an external IDP where users and machine clients are provisioned.
For end users, I can retrieve information about them using the /userinfo endpoint. This is useful in cases where, for example, a user submits an order via my API and I want to grab details about the user.
But what if a machine placed an order via my API? How should I glean information about the machine which placed the order? Using its access token, I only have access to a few claims, such as sub. There is no endpoint I can access which gives any additional information about the client. Should I put custom claims in the token? I'm wondering if there's a more canonical approach.

Any reason why you can't make a similar endpoint that tells the client this information?

OAuth doesn't provide a standardized solution for this, so you need to design your own.
REQUIREMENTS
I would reason about it like this:

Ensure that your API can differentiate clients so that you can authorize them differently when required.

Ensure that you design access tokens with least privilege for both machine clients and user-facing clients.

Ensure that your API applies all the correct authorization rules for both types of clients.


TECHNIQUES
These are techniques I would consider:

Map client IDs to your own client metadata. This is sometimes business permissions that can be easier to manage outside of access tokens.

Machine clients use the client credentials flow to get an access token. You can
issue custom claims to tokens to represent the main identity values. Eg if a machine client is from a business partner you might issue a partner_id claim.

Sometimes each machine client is given its own OAuth client ID, so that you can deny access to one of them without impacting others.

Sometimes it can make sense to use distinct API entry points for machine clients and user-facing apps. Eg. a machine client for a nightly batch job might connect using an endpoint that is not exposed to the internet and supply tokens with higher privileges than user facing apps. You might decide to use an API endpoint like /batch/orders to handle these differences.


